# Why do I get such different times in SoapUI and Visual Studio load tests?

Tags: visual-studio, soapui, load-testing

We have been running some load tests using SoapUI and getting some 'strange' results.

We call a service which does nothing except generate a guid and returns and finding that this sometimes takes >500ms (and occasionally over 3 seconds) these requests are distributed through the test run.

We have recently run the same test in Visual Studio Load tests and find that against the same deployment we don't see these 'slow' results, with all requests being <125 ms apart from the first request for each user.

Both test machines are hosted in Azure (Western Europe) and the deployment is in Eastern Europe.  The visual studio tests used 2 agents and the SoapUI ones were from a single machine, but we observe similar behaviour when we have 2 SoapUI instances.  I've run the tests against a single agent from VS and I get very similar results with only a few tests at the beginning being 'slow' (~500ms) but none over 3 seconds.  I immediately ran SoapUi against the same deployment and have 24 which SoapUI reports as having taken > 3000 ms.

What might be the cause of the (substantial) differences?  Am I missing some setting in SoapUI?